# Array of arrays "newing" syntax is backwards?

Tags: c#, arrays, jagged-arrays

In C#, when you "new" an array, it looks like this:

```csharp
int[] someArray = new int[5];
```

Which I read as:

```plaintext
int-array someArray = new int-array-of-size-5
```

Today I casually tried to create an array of arrays like so:

```csharp
int[][] someArray = new int[][5];
```

To me, that made intuitive sense - I would read it like:

```plaintext
int-array-array someArray = new int-array-array-with-size-5
```

However, after getting a confusing error and googling it, I found that it should [be written this way instead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays):

```csharp
int[][] someArray = new int[5][];
```

That doesn't make sense to me - because I read it like so:

```plaintext
int-array-array someArray = new int-array-with-size-5-array
```

But I'm not creating an array of size-5-int-arrays, I'm creating an array of int-arrays with size 5.

What is the underlying design rationale for the syntax? How am I intended to interpret `int[5][]` - what mental model can I use to make sense of this syntax?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2009/08/17/arrays-of-arrays/

Comment: `new int[5][]` create an array of length `5` of integer arrays.

Comment: new array of size 5 that can store int arrays.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko What you say would make sense if the syntax were something like `new [5]int[]`.

Comment: @HansPassant Same as above

Comment: @Clonkex: I doubt if  `new [5]int[]` is more readable than `new int[5][]`: `new [5]` fragment looks suspicius for me: we create - `new` - but what? - and then take 5th item of it `[5]` then it's followed by array declaration `int[]`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I agree entirely. I'm not saying it should be like `new [5]int[]`. I'm just saying the interpretation you offered only makes sense if that's the case.

Comment: @Dennis_E Thank you for the blog post! That's... crazy. Like seriously, I can't believe they actually chose to do it that way. So if I'm understanding this correct, `int[,][]` _isn't_ actually a 1D array of 2D arrays, it's a 2D array of 1D arrays. If that's true, that's a massive "WTF, why would anyone do that??" moment for me. Up until now C# has been by far the most sensibly-designed language to me. At least dereferencing is still sane, even if declaration and initialisation isn't. If you can summarise the blog post as an answer I'll accept it; otherwise I'll write my own later on.

Comment: *"because the C# devs wanted to avoid weirdness"" is subjective, and not really answerable without the C# devs themselves. The second question is more legit. The answer is really: the type specification doesn't define the length of the array as part of the type, so it makes no sense to create an array-of-5-ints, it's just an array-of-arrays-of-ints. Therefore you cannot create such an array using the syntax `new int[][5]` because the second pair of brackets is part of the type, which has no length.

Comment: @Charlieface I disagree entirely. If I choose to create my program with a particular behaviour, then that's the reason the program has that behaviour. No other reason. The reason it's the way it is is precisely and exclusively because C# devs decided it should be that way to make it more intuitive for users. When Eric Lippert says it's so, that's good enough for me. Besides all that, answering "why is it so?" is entirely possible without the C# dev team. All you need is a good source to reference. This is how 99% of all answers work. So yeah, could not disagree more lol.

Comment: Correct, but often with this kind of question it basically comes down to "that's how devs felt would be best at the time" and there is no record of that conversation (sometimes they don't remember themselves). Eric Lippert himself often says the same, and he was involved in the C# spec well over ten years ago now. Often the answer is "that's how it was always done (in C/C++)" or "noone had the money to invest to do it differently". It's just really subjective unless you literally have an exact record of the conversations. And sorry but "lol" is a rather derisive finish to a comment.

Comment: @Charlieface And yet, the blog post is from 2009 and seems pretty clear-cut to me. I just don't see how this could be considered opinion-based. It's very rare that no one knows _why_ a language feature was designed the way it is. There's almost always a reason, good or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Array of arrays](https://ericlippert.com/2009/08/17/arrays-of-arrays/)
As this blog post explains, they wanted to keep the order of brackets the same when creating an array and when accessing elements of the array. I'll try to summarize.
When you access an array like this:

```
array[1][2]
```

that means: take the array at index 1 and get the element of that array at index 2.
So, when creating the array, you have to initialize it like so:

```
new int[5][]
```

which means an object that holds 5 int arrays.
Weirdness cannot be avoided. Either the order of the brackets is weird when creating the array or the order is weird when accessing the array. The weirdest option would be when the order is different both times.

Comment: Personally I think weirdness can be entirely avoided by not trying to be excessively clever about it. I don't think it's weird at all that declaration/initialisation is reversed from dereferencing. That's just... normal. `int[]` would be an array of ints, `int[,][]` would be an array of 2D arrays of ints. Type comes first, then the indicator that it's an array of that type. But that's what they chose to do, so this is the correct answer  Thanks!

Comment: Note that this question is being discussed [on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423897/522444)